# Search feature, boolean operators?

Tags: discussion, search

I found this page, while trying to figure out why I can't use the boolean operators `AND` (conjunction) and `NOT` (negation), while `OR` (disjunction) works. (I simply wrote my search query as `[PHP] OR [Excel]` and then I tried `[PHP] NOT [laravel]` and it had no affect.)

https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

After doing a bit of digging, I realized that, in order to use these operators in the search query, you have to use & for conjunction and - for negation.

My question more or less why aren't negation and conjunction described in the link above?

I would suggest changing the subject "OR Operator" to "Boolean Operations" and adding the other two to the list. The help page is in need of revising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The negation operator is actually described in the page you're linking to, in the very first paragraph:

> To *exclude* results from a tag, term or phrase, prefix it with `-` in your query: `waffles -unicorns` finds posts that mention tasty batter-based breakfasts without including mythical creatures, while `[laurel] -[hardy]` includes only posts pertaining to the first half of the classic comedy couple.

You don't need `&` for AND; you just type the two terms you're searching for separated by a space. That's exactly how Google works, so users should be familiar with this and it doesn't need further explanation.

Comment: Hmm, I must have missed that! And I didn't know you could just search like that. Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, note that on the search results page, there's a link 'Advanced search tips' right next to the Search button, giving you some quick tips about searching.